# Is it possible to migrate a Sharepoint Server 2013 site to Sharepoint Foundation 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

Our customer did not told us that his server is running sharepoint foundation. We developed the site in sharepoint server.  I've tried doing a standard Restore-SPSite but when I access to the site it only shows a blank page. Everything works fine when I restore the site in another Sharepoint Server instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foundation is subset of the SharePoint Server, so most probably the customization you build which depend upon some feature which is not avaiable in SharePoint foundation thats why it is not working.

There are couple of things to try.

1. Redevelop the customization in SharePoint Foundation.

Or you can try below steps (its depend upon your customization, in this way you will get content at least):

1. In your development server, turn off the SharePoint Server features on the Site collection level.
2. Test if your customization still working.
3. take the backup of content database, move to the foundation farm.
4. Restore the db and mount to the Web application.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b82c9818-f6fc-4a1a-8166-11c4dd6d82dc/downgrade-from-sharepoint-server-to-foundation?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported as you cannot fully remove Standard/Enterprise features. Likewise, it is not supported to downgrade from Enterprise to Standard.